# Xaml Adaptive layout issues

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
<Page
x:Class="Salat_Pro.HomePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Salat_Pro"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">



<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition   Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Height="213" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Width="175">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/prayertimelogo.jpg" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Text="Prayer Times"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Height="213" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Width="175">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/qiblalogo.jpg" Height="155" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" Text="Qibla Direction"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Height="213" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Width="175">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/howtopraylogo.jpg" Height="140" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Text="How To Pray?"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Height="213" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Width="175">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/quranlogo.jpg" Height="140" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Text="Quran"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>



</Grid>

</Page>
```

[image: What I Am getting on my Desktop]

How It is ^

[image: How I want it to look on my Desktop]

How I want it to be ^

Upon viewing the design I saw that there isn't any issue even for 13.3 inch display(my is 15.4)! But I don't want so much of space wasted on my right. I had corrected this issue before but unfortunately lost the data.My solution to it was simple.Maybe something about Horizontal/Vertical Alignment. After pondering over it for 2 days I decided to post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the part that contains your `Page` with `Grid` doesn't use all space of window. Add a background color to `Page` and another color to `Grid`. In this way you should be able to understand where is the problem.

Comment: This indeed was the issue. I now manually set the grid to occupy entire  screen space available to it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Button Width="Auto" (maybe Height="Auto" too)

Comment: No it didn't work and the output is the same. I want the image embedded inside the button to be at the center of the button while I want the button to dock in Grid Cell

Comment: try playing with HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" in your Image tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the content of each Button,

An StackPanel makes it size upon its content, you should use a Grid

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/LockScreenLogo.png" Stretch="None" />
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

With that your buttons will get the full size with the content center aligned.